# Does installing the package rgdal also install GDAL on your computer?

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal

When I look at the documentation of the package rgdal it says

"The R contributed package rgdal is available from CRAN as a source package for installation on platforms with the full build train and external dependencies."

GDAL is one of the external dependencies, so I though this meant that it would download off CRAN and be installed along with the package.

When I load the package rgdal into my R workspace, I get this message:

```
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
 Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/andersonch/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rgdal/gdal
 GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/andersonch/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rgdal/proj
 Linking to sp version: 1.4-1
```

Again, I would have thought that means that there is a valid version of GDAL that the package is connecting to.

But when I try to use functions from the gdalUtils package, I get this warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan = ignore.full_scan, verbose = verbose) :
  No GDAL installation found. Please install 'gdal' before continuing:
    - www.gdal.org (no HDF4 support!)
    - trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ (with HDF4 support RECOMMENDED)
    - www.fwtools.maptools.org (with HDF4 support)

2: In gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan = ignore.full_scan, verbose = verbose) :
  If you think GDAL is installed, please run:
gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan=FALSE)"
```

Does this mean that I need to install gdal separately?